# Three intervals with minimum difference

Tags: algorithm

Lets assume we are given a sequence of `A`s and `B`s, e.g. `ABABBAAB`. We want to pick two points such that "cutting" the sequence in this points will result in getting three intervals and in every of them, the difference between `A`s and `B`s is minimal.

By cutting we mean literally deleting one letter in the beggining cut and one in the second cut.

Comment: Cand we see what you have tried and where is your error ? SO helpes you with your code, not giving your code or do your homework.

Comment: When is the combined difference minimal? E.g., would (1, 2, 3) be more minimal than (2, 2, 2), or would they be considered the same? Also, did I understand this correct, that you not only cut the sequence, but also remove the 2x2 characters adjacent to the cuts?